# MariaDB Query slower after mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB server with several databases.

On my MariaDB server, some queries (with joins between tables of different databases) are slower after the daily mysqdump (one file sql by database).

After the daily mysqldump, the first run for one query will be 1.5 minutes  and the second run 3.2 secondes (this time is coherent with current run on the day).
I understand the second run is faster but why the first run after the daily mysqldump is slower ? And how improve it ?

An extrait of my server.cnf :

`key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 2000
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
query_cache_limit= 128M
query_cache_size= 256M
query_cache_strip_comments=1
thread_concurrency = 8
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 3
innodb_log_file_size = 448M 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 210`

Thanks for you help.

Comment: have you tried timings without the query cache?  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Comment: Yah. I tried with SQL_NO_CACHE on each run. same result. To be sure it was not a problem with the query_cache, I tried with the query_cache disabled. Same resulsts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First query could be slow as the innodb buffer has been filled up with the queries required for the mysqldump and all the data needs to be fetched from disk.

You could run `SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now=1` before the dump and `SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_load_now=1` after the dump to ensure the buffer pool is what it was prior.

Comment: I tried it. In developpement environnement, I had some good results. So I am trying in one production environnement. I will do a feedback tomorrow. Thanks for your advice danblack !

Comment: I had good results in production too. I will do it in all our productions environnements. thank for it.

Comment: Good. [innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct) defaults to 25 pct in later versions so there may be tradeoffs with more or less of the pool. The other alternative is to dump from a replication slave.

Comment: I noticed it. I put this parameter on my server.cnf and I will change it if necessary according to performances.

Comment: thanks very useful info. Do I understand correctly when `xtrabackup` is used, it doesn't fill the innodb bufferspace with uneeded queries?

Comment: Correct, `xtrabackup` copies tablespaces directly while watching/checkpointing parts of the innodb internals to maintain consistency.